# NSOperationQueue - running synchronously

Tags: nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I need to make some API calls and I want to ensure that they come back in the order that they went out. Is this the proper flow to have that happen?

1. Create NSOperationQueue, set max concurrent operations to 1
2. Create URL String to API
3. Create NSOperation block, call method to call API, pass URL string
4. Add NSOperation to NSOperationQueue

This is where I get confused. Setting the max concurrent operations to 1 essentially makes NSOperationQueue into a synchronous queue, only 1 operation gets called at a time. However, each operation is going to make a NSURLSession call, which is async. How can I ensure that the next operation doesn't run until I have finished with the first? (By finish I want to store the returned JSON in a NSArray, adding each additional returned JSON to that array).

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to ensure that `NSOperation`s run in order is to add dependencies.  Dependencies are powerful as they allow ordering of different operations on different queues.  You can make an API call or data processing on a background queue; when complete, a dependent operation can update the UI on the main thread.

```
let operation1 = NSBlockOperation { 
    print("Run First - API Call")
}

let operation2 = NSBlockOperation { 
    print("Run Second - Update UI")
}
operation2.addDependency(operation1)

let backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()
backgroundQueue.addOperation(operation1)
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperation(operation2)

// operation1 will finish before operation2 is called, regardless of what queue they're in
```

See Apple Docs on `addDependency` in `NSOperation` here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperation

Also, be careful with assuming that `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` as all that it does is ensure that only 1 operation will run at a time.  This does NOT ensure the order of the queue.  An operation with a higher priority will likely run first.